# jQuery UI dialog and Ajax POST in asp.net

Tags: jquery, web-services

In the example below, how can i post data to webservice after clicking login button in asp.net?

```
 

        $(document).ready(function () {
        var username=$("#username").val();
        var password=$("#pass").val();

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                bgiframe: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 400,
                width: 300,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Login":function() {
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    url:"WebService.asmx/Login",
                    contentType:"application/json",
                    data:"{username:'"+username+"',password:'"+password+"'}",
                    success:function(val)
                    {
                    $("#isValid").attr("value",val.d);
                    }}
                    );
                    },
                },
            });

            var isValid = $("#isValid").val();
            if (isValid== "false") {
                // Display the modal dialog.
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you add an "error:" property to your .ajax call and get the error information and post it here? It's difficult to determine what your issue is without more information.

Comment: @Charles Boyoung:My requirement is to post data to webservice after clicking the login button

Comment: @santosh - and what isn't working? Doing what I said will give you an error message that will help determine why what you have isn't working.

Comment: @Charles:After clicking login button i want to post the value of two text boxes named username and password to webservice.

Comment: @santosh - That's fine. You still haven't explained what isn't working with what you have posted.

Comment: @Charles:After clicking Login button i am not getting any response or error.

Comment: @santosh - how do you know you aren't getting an error? You aren't using the "error" property in your ajax call, which means that any errors are just getting lost. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and look at the error property to see how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following signature on your WebService...

```
function bool Login(string userName, string password)
```

You just need to provide a javascript object in the JSON-notation that looks like this:

```
{ "userName" : "Admin", "password": "1234" }
```

Hint: make sure that the names in the javascript object do have the same name and casing... Makes life much easier.

Hope I understood your question correctly...

Comment: I am looking for postback after button click

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You're not being very clear. This should've answered your question.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa:My requirement is to post data to webservice after clicking the login button